# How to create something like a mobile homepage with lists of apps?

Tags: android, xml

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAXsh.png)I want to create something like our mobile phone home screen layout, where there are many apps with their names (including text below the image buttons). How can I do that? I don't want the grey background behind the images. Is there any way that I can remove it?

I tried using a `GridView` but I don't really like the huge box around the button since I am trying to use an `Imagebutton`. Also I can't use `layout_weight` with `GridView`.

This is what I have:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        >

    <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/gallery_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/Attach_Gallery"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            />
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:text=""/>
    <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/Camera_Button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/Attach_Camera"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/Attach_Gallery"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/gallery_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/Attach_Gallery"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I want the text can be under each image button and I also want a 2x4 chart with the image buttons and text.

Comment: Just attached the image with link. Sorry, I can't make it pretty, its the first time I am asking question up here...

Comment: `GridView` background can be changed, investigate more https://www.raywenderlich.com/995-android-gridview-tutorial Also, no need to use `ImageButton` if you don't want the button background, a simple `ImageView` is clickable as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can also add recycler view on your home screen Layout XML with Recycler View,
You have to add recycler view dependency as well into your app level build.gradle file
as

```
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
```

You can create a Simple List view, Staggered Layout, as well as Grid Layout.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rv_summary"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:numColumns="3"/>
```

After that, you have to create a Custom adapter for your recycler view like.

```
  RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager1 = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 3);
    rvSummary.setLayoutManager(layoutManager1);
    rvSummary.setAdapter(alarmSummaryAdapter);
```